# How to rxecute an ad-hoc stored procudure in UNIX shell script? Also is it possible to have IF-ELSE/WHILE LOOPS in sql-plus?

Tags: unix, plsql, sqlplus

I have a three part question which arises out of my following requirement. I have been asked to automate some stored procedures using shell scripts. Earlier the nature of the stored proc(not the definition, but the way of executing in PL/SQL) used to be like this

```
begin
  SP_RTB_UPDATE('DECLARE v_var1;
                 begin
                   INSERT INTO TRADINGACCOUNT(TAEXTREFSEQID, TRADINGACCOUNTID,
                                              LASTUPDATEDBY, LASTUPDATEDATE,
                                              EXTERNALSYSTEMREFERENCEVALUE)
                      VALUES (SEQ_TA_EXT_REF_ID.NEXTVAL,12345,
                              9999,sysdate,
                              v_var1) 
                      RETURNING TAEXTREFSEQID INTO V_PK;

                   INSERT INTO EXTREFSTATUS( TAEXTREFSEQID, SINCEDATETIME, 
                                             STATUSID, LASTUPDATEDBY )
                     VALUES ( V_PK, SYSDATE, 54, 9999 );');
end;
```

So basically, the stored proc is an adhoc one which accepts the entire query as the first parameter. Internally, the proc runs some audit tables (along with the query) to store the maintain the history/changes. Now, what I want to do it design a shell script that can automate the stored proc without manual intervention.

I have done something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please enter your username"

read DBUSER

echo "Please enter your password"

read DBUSERPASSWORD

echo "Please enter the Database name"

read DBSID

sqlplus -S $DBUSER/$DBUSERPASSWORD@$DBSID <<EOF

if [ $? -eq 0 ]

then

            echo "Connection OK"

            echo "Please insert the RMS code to be added"

            read RMS

            INSERT INTO TRADINGACCOUNT(TAEXTREFSEQID,TRADINGACCOUNTID,
                                       LASTUPDATEDBY, LASTUPDATEDATE, 
                                       EXTERNALSYSTEMREFERENCEVALUE )
              VALUES (SEQ_TA_EXT_REF_ID.NEXTVAL,12345,
                      9999,sysdate,
                      '$RMS')
              RETURNING TAEXTREFSEQID INTO V_PK;

         INSERT INTO EXTREFSTATUS( TAEXTREFSEQID, SINCEDATETIME,
                                   STATUSID, LASTUPDATEDBY )
           VALUES ( V_PK, SYSDATE, 54, 9999 );

   COMMIT;

ECHO "Done Successfully"
else
 echo "Connection NOT OK"
fi
```

Now there are many issue with this piece of code. Following are my doubts.

1.`if [  $? eq 0 ]..` is throwing error as "unknown command, remaining line neglected". So, is it possible to have IF-ELSE/WHILE loops in sqlplus(unix) statements

1. Also, the RETURNING INTO option of the INSERT statement is not working. What can be the possible equivalent of it when we run in UNIX(sqlplus)?

3.Is it at all possible to call the adhoc stored procedure from within the script with something like

```
execute SP_RTB_UPDATES('DECLARE v_var1....');
```

or we have to separate the queries and the write additional queries to handle the audit tables? But will this be as fail-safe as a stored proc?

Please advise. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a partial answer - you are mixing shell and sqplus commands 
You created a here document - which is very like typing directly into sqlplus.

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
```

is a shell command not sqlplus.  You will never get inside the here document if sqlplus fails.  Do not test to see if it worked that way.

```
sqlplus usr/pwsd@instance <<-EOF

-- sqlplus DML and PL/SQL only commands in here: SELECt, UPDATE, etc.    
EOF
[ $? -ne 0 ] && echo 'failure'
```

Likewise: `read RMS` before the here document.

With regard to creating the "whole command ad-hoc", use EXEC IMMEDIATE - Dynamic SQL

```
RMS=13
USER=foo
PSWD=foo
mycommand=$(printf "EXEC immediate 'select blah from table where blah = %s';"  "$RMS" )

sqlplus @USER/$PWSD/@instance <<-EOF
    $mycommand
EOF
```

The above is just  passing example, please learn how to do this here, please follow the links at the bottom of the page on Dynamic SQL:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm

Comment: Thanks for replying. Vlauable inputs, esp the diffence between sqlplus and unix commanline.Thanks!